# How to print only the value of an enum?

Tags: dart, enums

enum Move { rock, paper, scissors }

var playerMove = Move.rock;

print('Player played :${playerMove.name}');  <--- this line here gives me an error

print('AI played     :${aiMove.name}');    <--- this line works perfectly though

this is the error code:
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Move' has no instance getter 'name'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Move'
Tried calling: name

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'dart:math';

enum Move { rock, paper, scissors }
void main() {
  while (true) {
    final rng = Random();
    stdout.write('Rock, paper, scissors (r,p,s): ');
    final input = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (input == 'r' || input == 'p' || input == 's') {
      var playerMove;
      if (input == 'r') {
        playerMove = Move.rock;
      } else if (input == 'p') {
        playerMove = Move.paper;
      } else {
        playerMove = Move.scissors;
      }
      var random = rng.nextInt(3);
      var aiMove = Move.values[random];
      print('Input: $input');
      print('Player played :${playerMove.name}');
      print('AI played     :${aiMove.name}');
      if (playerMove == aiMove) {
        print("It's a draw");
      } else if (playerMove == Move.paper && aiMove == Move.rock ||
          playerMove == Move.rock && aiMove == Move.scissors ||
          playerMove == Move.scissors && aiMove == Move.paper) {
        print('Player win');
      } else {
        print('You lose');
      }
    } else if (input == 'q') {
      break;
    } else {
      print('Invalid input');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `.name` extension for `enum`s was added in Dart 2.15.  Does your `pubspec.yaml` file require a minimum Dart SDK version of 2.15.0 or later?

Comment: print('Player played :${playerMove.name}');   <-- this line gave me the error

Comment: print('AI played     :${aiMove.name}'); <-- but this line works perfectly fine

Comment: pubspec.yaml is already using Dart sdk version 2.15.1 and higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.name` is an extension on `enum`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/EnumName.html).  Dart extensions are *static*: [they are compile-time syntactic sugar, and they therefore require that the object's type be known at compilation time](https://medium.com/dartlang/extension-methods-2d466cd8b308).

You have code:

```dart
var playerMove;
if (input == 'r') {
  playerMove = Move.rock;
}
...
```

`var playerMove;` does not specify a type for the variable, and there is no initializer to infer its type from.  It therefore is implicitly declared as `dynamic`, and extensions on `enum` will not be applied to it.

You can fix it by specifying an explicit type:

```dart
Move playerMove;
```

Comment: @world `aiMove`'s type is inferred from its initializer (`Move.values[random]`).